Sitecore .tsx component not mapping props
I have a project with footer.tsx component in it. I am trying to load the next js project with npm run start:connected command and it is giving me the error as

It should map the properties on the GlobalFooterProps and my type is as follows:

I have connected my XM Cloud with my environment, and the content is also available in Sitecore. However, I'm not sure why it is still unable to map the data.
I also verified that the JSON Rendering for the global footer is already available in Sitecore.
Do you have any idea in this situation what should be the starting point to find the traces for such kind of errors?
Edit-1:
import type { Field, ImageField, LinkField } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
import type { ComponentProps } from 'lib/component-props';
import { Text, Placeholder } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs';
import { isEditorActive } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs/utils';
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { MediaLink } from 'common/HashLink/HashLink';
import styles from './GlobalFooter.module.scss';

type GlobalFooterProps = ComponentProps & {
  fields?: {
    data?: {
      item?: GlobalFooterFields;
    };
  };
};

type GlobalFooterFields = {
  Copyright?: {
    jsonValue?: Field<string>;
  };
  LegalCopy?: {
    jsonValue?: Field<string>;
  };
  Logo?: {
    jsonValue?: ImageField;
  };
};

const GlobalFooter = ({ fields = {}, rendering }: GlobalFooterProps) => {
  
  const {
    //LogoLink = {},
    Logo = {},
    Copyright = {},
    LegalCopy = {},
    children = {},
  } = fields?.data?.item as GlobalFooterFields;

  return (

      <footer className="GlobalFooter">
        <div className="GlobalFooter_columns">
          {Logo.jsonValue?.value?.src && (
            <div className="GlobalFooter_logo">
              <HashLink
                //link={LogoLink.jsonValue}
                image={Logo.jsonValue}
                role="heading"
                aria-level="1"
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </footer>

  );
};

export default GlobalFooter;

Edit - 2: As per the suggestions I checked the following layout query in GraphQL IDE for my home page:
query { 
      layout(language: "en", routePath: "/", site: "mysitename") { 
        item { 
          rendered 
        } 
}

and in the response of this, I did not see any field that corresponds to the Copyright, Logo and LegalCopy field as expected in the .tsx component, as shown in screenshot. So, what could be the reason, but data is available in these fields in my Sitecore.
Edit - 3:
From my local the layout response in the route object is as something:
"jss-footer": [
                {
                  "uid": "527401e4-b820-4320-b10a-29f5b8b7a21a",
                  "componentName": "PartialDesignDynamicPlaceholder",
                  "dataSource": "",
                  "params": {
                    "sid": "{527401E4-B820-4320-B10A-29F5B8B7A21A}",
                    "ph": "jss-footer",
                    "sig": "sxa-global-footer"
                  },
                  "placeholders": {
                    "sxa-global-footer": [
                      {
                        "uid": "07b4341d-802b-42a0-bdc0-9e350aabe5ab",
                        "componentName": "GlobalFooter",
                        "dataSource": "{5C817C52-7658-442C-BA3B-644832006F0A}",
                        "params": {
                          "DynamicPlaceholderId": "1",
                          "FieldNames": "Default"
                        },
                        "placeholders": {
                          "jss-footerstatelinks": [
                            {
                              "uid": "b9bd45f4-f7f9-4f10-b549-f45c0f590b81",
                              "componentName": "FooterStateLinks",
                              "dataSource": "{09A99EDC-1D3E-4D76-808D-C5E4773A8310}"
                            },
                            {
                              "uid": "88b88319-f4ce-418e-be09-314359f887e4",
                              "componentName": "FooterStateLinks",
                              "dataSource": "{93E4F9B8-2D18-40C5-BCD1-EE1669A4A452}"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }

If you see in the JSON above the component "GlobalFooter" is available (as you can see in the JSON as "componentName": "GlobalFooter" ) on the home page and dataSource property is also showing with the ItemID, but, after params there should have been one more property as fields that actually contains the datasource item's data.
Then, I checked the response on the dev environment and it gives the fields property with long list of the datasource item's fields and its respective data and this is not coming locally. We have taken the exact data from dev to our local.

Can you also provide the code for Footer.tsx file and your Layout response for the footer component? It's not straightforward to identify the error based on the information provided, as there might be an issue in the layout response or in the footer.tsx file

How to get the layout response, please let me know?

As you are working with XM Cloud, you can go to "https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/ide" and execute the query for your page. I hope you are aware of this, if not refer this Documentation of sitecore.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/set-up-the-graphql-playgrounds-to-test-published-content.html#set-up-the-delivery-api-playground
Once you receive the response, you can paste it in the question, especially the footer placeholder, along with your footer.tsx file.

Try to run the query in the GraphQL sandbox and see if you can see the logo field there.

Okay, let me check in GraphQL play ground locally. because I am working locally with docker.

@AkshayBarve I have modified the question as per your requirement. Please check.

I checked the Footer component having the query in the component GrahQL query field on rendering, something like this:
query GlobalFooter($datasource: String!) {
  item: item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
    id
    Copyright: field(name: "Copyright") {
      jsonValue
    }
    LegalCopy: field(name: "LegalCopy") {
      jsonValue
    }
    Logo: field(name: "Logo") {
      jsonValue
    }
    LogoLink: field(name: "LogoLink") {
      jsonValue
    }

So I tried to run this query in the GraphQL play ground with hard coded $datasource passed as variable and then I received the following error:
ERROR Error: GraphQL error: Query is too complex to execute. The field with the highest complexity is: Field{name='template',.....

So, I got the answer on my other question DataSource item's fields object is not coming in the layout service in graphql that increasing the serializationMaxDepth, maxDepth and maxComplexity can resolve the error so I patched the config as follows:
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
               xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/"
               xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/"
               xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/">
    <sitecore>
    <api>
      <GraphQL>
        <defaults>
          <security>
            <publicService type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Security.GraphQLSecurity, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL">
              <complexityConfiguration type="GraphQL.Validation.Complexity.ComplexityConfiguration, GraphQL">
                <maxDepth>50</maxDepth>
                <maxComplexity>20000</maxComplexity>
              </complexityConfiguration>
            </publicService>
          </security>
        </defaults>
      </GraphQL>
    </api>
    <layoutService>
      <serializationMaxDepth>8</serializationMaxDepth>
    </layoutService>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

And this worked.

Without looking at your experience edge schema (JSON Schema) of how components are put up and how they are reading the datasource etc. it will be hard to tell anything
Can you provide layout query response? so we know what schema is coming and see props mapping?
If you have not publish the content on experience edge, It is ok to provide preview API response too if that works
To open the GRAPHQL IDE, do following

From XM Cloud dashboard, open deploy app
Go to projects and click your project
Now from the list select environment
Once you are in environment, go to Details tab on top and find the IDE links, Click them and they should take you to GQL IDE and over there you can fire layout query


To me, It looks like its only about changing your .tsx props to match the structure of your JSON response, There could be some minor mistake.

I want run the playground locally but I get 404 while accessing the https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/authoring/graphql/playground/. So to run the graphql for xmcloucm.localhost will this also require settings as you suggested in your answer?

Can you check by changing to below:
const GlobalFooter = ({ fields, rendering }: GlobalFooterProps) => {
const {
//LogoLink = {},
Logo,
Copyright,
LegalCopy,
children,
} = fields?.data?.item as GlobalFooterFields;

Just removing the empty initaialisations.

@Daivagna Nanavati, I checked the layout response and in the response of this, I did not see any field that corresponds to the Copyright, Logo and LegalCopy field. So what to check next

@George - First of all is your GlobalFooter component is in headless-footer placeholder? can you try to see the layout service response of the page where these components are? It could be possible that you copy paste the GQL of layoutsrvice and it might be returning Home page where component might not be there, Or connect with me on slack, We can troubleshoot

I wish I could but due to some polices I am unable to join. If possible, I have updated the question with layout response. But I really appreciate for the help you are providing here.

Hi @george - Can you try to connect to your DEV environment from local? in your .env.local file, point it to your remote dev instance and with that API key of DEV and do npm run start:connected and see if it works? If YES that means there is something missing in your local which on DEV
